# Initializing collection while creating object from XMLSerializer

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I'm using the WCF DataContractSerializer to serialize and deserialize a large object graph in my application. My problem is that if I have a collection that is initialized on the field declaration, the DataContractSerializer does not run that initialization, and the collection ends up null.

For example:

```
class Test
{
    List<string> collection = new List<string>();

    public List<string> Collection 
    {
         get { return collection; } 
    }
}
```

After serializing and deserializing this class, the collection will be null instead of the default new. If I move the initialization into the property get, it works ok.

Since I have a pretty large object graph, going through all the places that this happens is rather time consuming. I'd prefer if there was a way to do this automatically somehow.

Update: I'm using the WCF DataContractSerializer, so I guess that's why it doesn't initialize the collection.

Can the regular XML Serializer handle recursive references as I've got those in my entity?

Update: Ok, so now I'm stuck... to be more specific, the entities are used for NHibernate, so they do have DataContract/DataMember on them. But then I'm using IList for the BelongsTo/HasMany properties, and XMLSerializer doesn't serialize those either, and with the no recursive references, that's a no go either.

So, assuming we have a class that uses IList, and has recursive references, is there a way I can serialize/deserialize it and still run the default object constructors ?

Update: did some more tests, looks like I'm going to have to come up with a hybrid of my own, as NH requires the IList, which restricts me to DCS, and its tag along problems...

Comment: It should work this way, in my app I do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` runs the constructor / field-initialisers; the code as-written should be fine. Are you perhaps usig `DataContractSerializer` (i.e. WCF) instead? (DCS *doesn't* run constructors).

A handy hack for WCF is:

```
get {
    return list ?? ( list = new List<string>() );
}
```

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact I am using DCS. I did not know that difference. In that case, I've got recursive references in my entity, which is why I've used DCS. Can XML Serializer handle recursive references ?

Comment: @miki also, to properly use DCS you should add DatContract/DataMember attributes

Comment: @miki final point; you can also use deserialization callbacks with DCS (to init fields etc), but that is even more fadf

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to resolve this is to initialize the collection in the default constructor.

Comment: As far as the CLI is concerned, field initialisers **are** part o the constructor. For `XmlSerializer` the code should be fine as written in the question.

Comment: That's what I would have thought... trusted the OP's observation to the contrary, but it looks like you were right, he's not using an XmlSerializer as he said

Comment: You're right, I just noticed that I did mentioned XMLSerializer all the time instead. Will fix.